# Using binary space partition to lay out scenes in game

Tags: vector, procedural-generation, tilemap, binary-space-partitioning, godot

**Q:** How can I randomly lay out these house scenes in the larger scene such that they don't overlap?

I'm using the [Godot Engine](http://www.godotengine.org) to create a little 2D RPG kind of game. I'm laying out a village in a procedural fashion where the largest house is first put down, then the smaller house, and so on. These houses are set in a [`tilemap`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tilemap.html), and that itself is set in a larger `tilemap` scene. I've tried randomly setting them up by using a random value in a [`Vector2`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector2.html?highlight=vector2) object, but they may overlap one another. After a lot of experimentation, I happened upon an article about [binary space partitions](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-bsp-trees-to-generate-game-maps--gamedev-12268) and sought to find an example of this made in the Godot Engine. I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFgDjvLXq2g) on YouTube and used that code to make a small function:

```
func bsp(map_size_width, map_size_height):
    var rec1
    var rec2
    var back = []
    var contents = [[0, 0, map_size_width, map_size_height]]
    for i in range(0, 4):
        back.clear()
        for rec in contents:
            randomize()
            if rec[2] > rec[3]:
                var width = round(rand_range(0.3,0.7) * rec[2])
                rec1 = [rec[0], rec[1], width, rec[3]]
                rec2 = [rec[0]+width, rec[1], rec[2]-width, rec[3]]
            else:
                var height = round(rand_range(0.3,0.7) * rec[3])
                rec1 = [rec[0], rec[1], rec[2], height]
                rec2 = [rec[0], rec[1] + height, rec[2], rec[3] - height]
            back.append(rec1)
            back.append(rec2)
        contents.clear()
        for r in back: contents.append(r)
    return contents
```

To use it, I pass the size of the scene (in units of tiles) in the `tilemap` and it spits out an array which holds the origin of each rectangle, as well as its width and height. An example output looks like this:

```
[[0, 0, 7, 7], [7, 0, 13, 7], [0, 7, 6, 14], [6, 7, 14, 14], [20, 0, 10, 4], [20, 4, 10, 7], [20, 11, 10, 4], [20, 15, 10, 6], [0, 21, 8, 4], [0, 25, 8, 5], [8, 21, 4, 5], [8, 26, 4, 4], [12, 21, 5, 5], [12, 26, 5, 4], [17, 21, 6, 9], [23, 21, 7, 9]]
```

And a more visual example that could use this function looks like this:

[image: A visual representation of a binary space partition]

Now all I need to do is figure out how to assign one house to one fitting rectangle. I have tried first matching the size of the house scene to a matching element in the array. However, this, too, can lead to overlapping houses. Then I thought of taking out the element when it's matched with a house element. But this can lead to house scenes which don't even get counted.

FWIW, here's the current code that I'm using:

```
# House 1
var h1 = get_node("House1").get_used_rect().size
# House2
var h2 = get_node("House2").get_used_rect().size
# House 3
var h3 = get_node("House3").get_used_rect().size
# Our function in action.
var binary_things = bsp(world_tile_width, world_tile_height)
# Holds the data for the house scenes
var coor = []
# Set the largest house, "h3", first.
for i in [h3,h2,h1]:
    # Go through and compare the sizes of the houses.
    for g in range( binary_things.size() ):
         # If there is a match, append it to the "coor" array.
         if binary_things[g][2] > i.width and binary_things[g][3] > i.height:
             coor.append(binary_things[g])
             # Remove it from circulation.
             binary_things.remove(g)
             break
# Create the Vector2 objects for the houses.
var w = Vector2( coor[0][0], coor[0][1] )
var v = Vector2( coor[1][0], coor[1][1] )
# In tests, it is found that the third element in the "coor" array is not filled.
var q = Vector2( coor[2][0], coor[2][1] )

# Convert the tile coordinates to pixel coordinates.
var translated1 = map_to_world(w)
var translated2 = map_to_world(v)
var translated3 = map_to_world(q)

# Set the scenes in the larger scenes.
scene_1.set_pos(translated1)
scene_2.set_pos(translated2)
scene_3.set_pos(translated3)
```

Comment: Presumably `h3` is the one that isn't fitting. If so, then I think you are splitting up the map too many times. If I understand that `bsp` function correctly then changing the range in `for i in range(0, 4):` to something smaller should work. You might still want a fallback layout in case all the houses don't fit if that makes them fit most of the time.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of using a fallback layout.